# Creating a type list of all constructors of a class

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement a lazy initialisation class, `lazy<T>`, that stores `T`'s construction arguments and uses them to construct a `T` the first time it's needed. Currently I'm capturing the arguments in a function object (stored in a `boost::function`) that constructs the object in a specified location when it's called; while this works, it requires a dynamic allocation, and I would like to avoid that.

I would like to use `boost::variant`, where the different variants are the different argument lists corresponding to `T`'s various constructors (assuming there aren't any template constructors) and `T` itself, so that the amount of memory needed will be known at compile-time. For that I need a compile-time way to assemble a list of all accessible constructors in `T`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There's no way to get real compile-time method introspection. Although if you know that there's a limited set of possible constructors, you can check whether each of them are present with some template meta-programing magic.

Comment: This question needs to be narrowed down a bit. It sounds like you're asking how to make a list of constructors (which isn't possible for the general case), but you really want to know how to replace `boost::function` (which is obsolete; you should use `std::function`) with something else. We need to see your `boost::function` code to have any idea.

Comment: I would use `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094052/how-can-i-create-a-stdfunction-with-a-custom-allocator` and coax the `std::function` to allocate into a buffer instead of the heap.  However, this means `lazy` must know of or contain such a buffer, which entails additional overhead and complexity.  I suggest just putting it on the heap.

Comment: Would you be okay with not having type erasure on the constructor arguments?  Then you could use a `union { T object; std::tuple<Args...> args; };` or something alike.  But this might waste memory if `sizeof(args) > sizeof(object)`.  As far as I know, `std::function` is already optimized to not allocate heap memory if the function object is sufficiently small so I'm not sure whether you will gain more than lots of trouble by not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 and a half versions in this answer:

- based on `variant<>`,
- based on `optional<>` and
- a version that doesn't actually take the constructor arguments, but instead takes a factory calleable. This might enable more reduction of dynamic allocations (but deviates a bit from the question)

### Boost Variant

**Update** Thanks to the comment by @5gon12eder I've created this, more elegant, version based on Boost Variant:

Note that Boost Variant does also **not** use dynamic memory allocation.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d9a1495fbf05e9)</kbd>**

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct Lazy {
    template <typename... Args> Lazy(Args const&... args) 
        : _storage(Factory([=] { return T(args...); }))
    { }

    T& get()             { return ensure(); }
    T const& get() const { return ensure(); }

    explicit operator bool() const { return _storage.which(); }

  private:
    using Factory = std::function<T()>;
    mutable boost::variant<Factory, T> _storage;

    T& ensure() const {
        if (!_storage.which())
            _storage = boost::get<Factory>(_storage)();

        return boost::get<T>(_storage);
    }
};

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Lazy<std::string> ls("Hello world");
    std::cout << ls.get() << "\n";

    // Lazy<std::string> oops(42.7, true); // no matching function call
}
```

The limitations are as with Boost Optional (see below). Note that with the variant the factory will be destructed at the time of instantiation, so if the argument types have expensive destructors this might be a efficiency factor to keep in mind.

### Boost Optional

> #### *[When To Use Boost Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/when_to_use_optional.html)*
>
> [...]
>
> Another typical situation is to indicate that we do not have a value yet, but we expect to have it later. This notion can be used in implementing solutions like lazy initialization or a two-phase initialization.

Note that Boost Optional does **not** use dynamic memory allocation.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d85d9cef754cda08)</kbd>**

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct Lazy {
    template <typename... Args> Lazy(Args const&... args) 
        : _factory([=] { return T(args...); })
    { }

    T& get()             { return *(_value? _value : _value = _factory()); }
    T const& get() const { return *(_value? _value : _value = _factory()); }

    explicit operator bool() const { return _value; }

  private:
    std::function<T()> _factory;
    mutable boost::optional<T> _value;
};

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Lazy<std::string> ls("Hello world");
    std::cout << ls.get() << "\n";

    // Lazy<std::string> oops(42.7, true); // no matching function call
}
```

Admittedly, this has limitations

- no proper deduction of brace-initialization lists,
- constructor arguments are required to be copyable (this restriction could probably be lifted without too much effort when using c++14)
- the type-erased `function<>` might still incur a dynamic allocation. Several implementations optimize this for small factory functors, using Small Object Buffer optimization, so *profile, profile, profile*.

  You might consider supplying the factory functor directly from the caller: 
  See this variation **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fde255737c70d3dc)**.

  - In a way this just shifts the burden - which may or may not matter
  - It does seem considerably less friendly to use on the call-site

---

Note as well it does early detection of the constructor arguments, so something like

```
Lazy<std::string> oops(42.7, true);
```

simply doesn't compile.

As a bonus, it has smart-pointer-like contextual conversion to bool. You will want to add more things (such as a hash<> specialization, and possibly IO operators that just defer to `boost::optionals` IO operator implementation)

Comment: As I understood the post, the only problem with his current code is that the `std::function` is allocating things on the heap.  This answer doesn't address that problem at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck As I read it, the problem is that he was requiring a dynamic allocation when creating the actual instance of the object :) And that is totally addressed by boost::optional.

Comment: @MooingDuck Scribbled some more ideas about further optimizing the factory into the answer, including a variation that may enable more optimized code: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de9efa90f5fc1eda)**. It largely depends on the use cases, though. I'd stick with the simple version and _profile, profile, profile_

Comment: I'd consider putting `factory` and `value` into an anonymous `union` (in which case you don't need `boost::optional` any more) so you can dispose of the constructor arguments once the object is constructed.  On the down-side, you'll need another `bool` member to remember whether the object was already constructed but in the general case, this should be less overhead than carrying the factory around forever.

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes. Here it is: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d9a1495fbf05e9)**, see also `#define BOOST_VARIANT_MINIMIZE_SIZE`. Note that, like `optional<>`, `variant` does not incur dynamic allocation

Comment: @sehe, completely unrelated, how do you make the nice button "Live on Coliru"? <kbd> </kbd> is verbatim-izing text, asaik, and ** makes it bold, how comes that yours is in a button?

Comment: @vsoftco You'll just have to try it to believe it, then: see the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @sehe oh wow :)) k, will improve my postings from now on :) wonder if this markup language is turing-complete, seems complicated enough :))))