# Copy-construct and later access arbitrary POD types

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to fill in the `store()` and `launch()` methods in the below code. The important detail which captures the spirit of the problem is that the object `foo` declared in `main()` no longer exists at the time we call `launch()`. How can I do this?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U=
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,T>::type>
struct Launchable {
  void launch() { /* some code here */ }

  T t;
  // other members as needed to support DelayedLauncher 
};

class DelayedLauncher {
public:
  template<typename T>
    void store(const Launchable<T>& t) {
      // copy-construct/memcpy t into some storage
    }

  void launch() const {
    // call t.launch(), where t is (a copy of) the last value passed into store()
  }

  // other members as needed
};

int main() {
  DelayedLauncher launcher;
  {
    Launchable<int> foo;
    launcher.store(foo);
  }
  launcher.launch();  // calls foo.launch()
  return 0;
}
```

Note that if we only had a fixed set of N types to pass into `store()`, we could achieve the desired functionality by declaring N `Launchable<T>` fields and N non-template `store()` methods, one for each type, along with an enum field whose value is use in a `switch` statement in the `launch()` method. But I'm looking for an implementation of `DelayedLauncher` that will not need modification as more `Launchable` types are added.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't simply add a member of the `Launchable<T>` type to `DelayedLauncher`, and implement `store` by calling `operator=` on that member.

Comment: If `Launchable<T>` doesn't implement an assignment operator, you can use `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I need my class to support `Launchable<int>`, `Launchable<float>`, etc.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but wouldn't your suggestion violate the requirement in my last paragraph? "But I'm looking for an implementation of `DelayedLauncher` that will not need modification as more `Launchable` types are added."

Comment: Does `DelayedLauncher` need to be a non-template class?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize `DelayedLauncher` is not a template. Now I understand the question.

Comment: Do you realize that `DelayedLauncher` looks a hell of a lot like `std::function`, functionality-wise?

Comment: @MarkB Yes, `DelayedLauncher` must be a non-template class.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I had never used `std::function` before so I didn't know to draw the connection. Jarod42's solution makes the connection clear.

Comment: Please see my answer, I have reproduced your `main()` using only `std::function` and no custom classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `std::function`:

```
class DelayedLauncher {
public:
  template<typename T>
    void store(const Launchable<T>& t) {
      f = [t]() {t.launch();};
    }

  void launch() const { f(); }

 private:
     std::function<void()> f;
};
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Surely, a lambda and/or `std::function` is unnecessary to fulfill the OP's task. Having said that, `Launchable` itself should probably be substituted for `std::function` entirely.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: As I understand OP's usage may store `Launchable<int>` than `Launchable<char>`, so we have to have some sort of type erasure (or take a clonable `ILaunchable`).

Comment: Great, this did the trick. This seems mysterious to me - is there some sort of dynamic memory allocation under the hood? If so, where exactly does it happen?

Comment: All the magic is in `std::function`, which indeed would do one dynamic allocation to do its type erasure and save the lambda.

Comment: I need `store()` to be as lightweight as possible. Is it possible to somehow supply my own allocator?

Comment: see [how-can-i-create-a-stdfunction-with-a-custom-allocator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094052/how-can-i-create-a-stdfunction-with-a-custom-allocator) for custom allocator.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Would you mind taking a look at my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561684/543913)? It is my attempt at extending yours to one that avoids dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You could give `Launchable` a base class with a virtual `launch()` and no template, and store pointers to that base class in `Launcher::store`.

EDIT: Adapted from @dshin's solution:

```
struct LaunchableBase {
    virtual void launch() = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename U=
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value,T>::type>
  struct Launchable : public LaunchableBase {
      virtual void launch() override { /* some code here */ }

      T t;
      // other members as needed to support DelayedLauncher 
  };

class DelayedLauncher {
    public:
        template<typename T>
            void store(const Launchable<T>& t) {
                static_assert(sizeof(t) <= sizeof(obj_buffer),
                        "insufficient obj_buffer size");
                static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value,
                        "leak would occur with current impl");
                p = new (obj_buffer) Launchable<T>(t);
            }

        void launch() const {
            p->launch();
        }

    private:
        char obj_buffer[1024];  // static_assert inside store() protects us from overflow
        LaunchableBase *p;
};
```

Comment: The pointer may no longer be valid when it comes time to launch().

Comment: @dshin You allocate the space and copy t in store(), just like your solution. Instead of making a closure around a local variable p, you just store it directly in a member named p and call p->launch() from DelayedLauncher::launch(). The idea is to use the abstract untemplated base of Launchable to erase the type of Launchable<T>. Using a lambda is a little more succinct, though.

Comment: I see. Still, I think my solution is preferable due to the fact that it incurs no dynamic allocation overhead.

Comment: @dshin FWIW, you'd allocate p in the exact same way you do it in your solution, and std::function has its own overhead that's at least as bad as a vtable lookup. On gcc 4.9, vtable is 6-7x faster than std::function if it can't optimize the lookup away, and about 75 thousand times as fast if it can. The compiler basically can't optimize std::function.

Comment: Incidentally, clang 3.7 performs unbelievably poorly in all cases compared to gcc for the toy program I wrote to compare vtable and std::function dispatch.

Comment: Are you talking about the cost of `store()`, or the cost of `launch()`? I need a fast `store()`, and don't care about the cost of `launch()`. Also, in my application there will be thousands of different types `T` of varying sizes of up to ~1000 bytes. `store()` might be called hundreds of times rapidly in succession before hitting a `launch()`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better communicate my intent. Hopefully that answers your questions.

Comment: Aha, I see. Yes, that works and avoids dynamic allocation, although there is a tradeoff of slower construction time of `Launchable` objects (due to vtable initialization) against the faster `launch()`. In my particular use case the tradeoff will not be worth it, but I could easily see your solution being preferable in a different context. I've changed my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99540/discussion-between-dshin-and-gary-jackson).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this variant of Jarod42's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560054/543913) will avoid dynamic allocation, although I would appreciate if someone could confirm that this will work the way I think it will:

```
class DelayedLauncher {
public:
  template<typename T>
    void store(const Launchable<T>& t) {
      static_assert(sizeof(t) <= sizeof(obj_buffer),
        "insufficient obj_buffer size");
      static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value,
        "leak would occur with current impl");
      auto p = new (obj_buffer) Launchable<T>(t);
      auto ref = std::ref(*p);
      f = [=]() {ref.get().launch();};
    }

  void launch() const {
    f();
  }

private:
  char obj_buffer[1024];  // static_assert inside store() protects us from overflow
  std::function<void()> f;
};
```

I believe it should work because the resources I've looked at indicate that `std::function` implementations typically have a "small capture" optimization, only triggering a dynamic allocation if the total size of the captured data exceeds some threshold.

---

EDIT: I replaced my code with a version provided by Jarod42 in the comments. The standard guarantees the above implementation will not trigger dynamic allocation.

Comment: You have to use placement new instead of `memcpy` and you don't remove allocation done by `std::function`.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>` mean that `memcpy` and placement new are equivalent?

Comment: I miss that part, indeed, but here you don't copy, you create a new object. I'm not sure if interpreting buffer as object in this code is not UB.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if it is UB for some reason. But to me the bigger question is why you say `std::function` still needs to allocate. I'm capturing a total of 8 bytes, and the sources I'm using ([example](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059?pgno=2)) seem to indicate that because 8 is small, those bytes can be stored statically. I'm finding the `std::function` header a bit hard to parse but I see a bool `__stored_locally` which appears to be related?

Comment: Small object optimization is guaranty for `std::reference_wrapper` and function pointer. it might be done in your case, but without guaranty.

Comment: something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a391bfd190c51afc) should be better.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help. This now gets me everything I want. I still have trouble imagining why small object optimization might not kick in for a pointer if it is guaranteed for a `std::reference_wrapper`. Maybe in practice it always will?

Comment: In practice, it will probably use this optimization I think.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've asked a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34599965/543913), basically asking if the same guarantee applies for std::bind() as does here with anonymous lambda. I'd appreciate your expertise there if you wouldn't mind. Thanks!