# Custom allocator for std::bind

Tags: c++, performance, function, allocator, stdbind

Perhaps the topic of `std::bind` and `std::function` is not clear enough to me - then, please, clarify. I'm trying to implement a thread pool (like [this](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h)), but to avoid `std::function` and `std::bind` performance penalty due to heap allocations for the asynchronous function parameters stored somewhere in `std::function` or `std::bind`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094052/how-can-i-create-a-stdfunction-with-a-custom-allocator) they explain how to provide a custom allocator to `std::function`. However, as I understand, custom allocator (for performance) should be provided to `std::bind` too. If not, then why? If yes, how?

EDIT1: if that matters, the custom allocator is going to allocate from a memory pool.

EDIT2: the compiler is MSVC++2017, so C++11/14/17 should (partially) work.

Comment: You don't need std::bind at all, use lambda.

Comment: @manni66 There is at least one use for `std::bind` which can't be copied with lambdas: [pre-C++14 move-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744730/2752075).

Comment: @manni66, as I understand, lambda will still be a class that will store the parameters in the heap. So the question just changes to "how to specify custom allocator for lambdas" in that case.

Comment: I don't believe a lambda requires any heap allocations, except to the extent that objects it captures by value allocate in their copy constructors. In fact, it could be argued that a lambda shall not perform heap allocations. The standard carefully spells out exactly what the class behind a lambda should look like; captures become data members of that class.

Comment: A lambda is essentially a struct with operator(). It has no memory management.